# Games stuttering about every 7 minutes

Tags: 12.10, graphics, xorg, games, logs

Whenever I play a game on my Linux machine, it stutters every 7 minutes or so for about 5 seconds. Seems like not a serious problem but it is still a bit annoying. So any ideas on how to even trace the cause of that bug and then maybe try to fix it too.

I have Ubuntu 12.10 installed on my Acer aspire 5552g which has a:

- AMD 2.20 GHz proccessor
- Radeon HD 5650 with the latest AMD proprietary drivers.
- 4 GB of RAM
- DE: Gnome 3

#### Updates:

1. I took a look at the CPU usage chart while the stutter occurred and it showed that one core (dual core) went up to 100% while this happened and the other one stayed like it was. Might it be a sign of a CPU failure or might it just be a bad OS install?
2. It seems to be a problem of Xorg actually. When the stuttering occurs, Xorg seems to take up about 60% of my CPU capacity.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot from here on?

Checking log files now and this is the list of the logs I have:

```
kaspar@kaspar-pc:/var/log$ ls
alternatives.log    btmp.1          jockey.log.2.gz     syslog.3.gz
alternatives.log.1  ConsoleKit      kern.log            syslog.4.gz
apport.log          cups            kern.log.1          syslog.5.gz
apport.log.1        dist-upgrade    kern.log.2.gz       syslog.6.gz
apport.log.2.gz     dmesg           kern.log.3.gz       syslog.7.gz
apport.log.3.gz     dmesg.0         kern.log.4.gz       udev
apport.log.4.gz     dmesg.1.gz      lastlog             ufw.log
apport.log.5.gz     dmesg.2.gz      lightdm             unattended-upgrades
apport.log.6.gz     dmesg.3.gz      mail.err            upstart
apport.log.7.gz     dmesg.4.gz      mail.log            wtmp
apt                 dpkg.log        news                wtmp.1
auth.log            dpkg.log.1      pm-powersave.log    Xorg.0.log
auth.log.1          faillog         pm-powersave.log.1  Xorg.0.log.old
auth.log.2.gz       fontconfig.log  pm-suspend.log      Xorg.1.log
auth.log.3.gz       fsck            pm-suspend.log.1    Xorg.1.log.old
auth.log.4.gz       gdm             samba               Xorg.2.log
boot                hp              speech-dispatcher   Xorg.2.log.old
boot.log            installer       syslog              Xorg.3.log
bootstrap.log       jockey.log      syslog.1            Xorg.failsafe.log
btmp                jockey.log.1    syslog.2.gz         Xorg.failsafe.log.old
```

And this is the tail -F of syslog:

```
kaspar@kaspar-pc:~$ tail -F /var/log/syslog
Feb 23 00:39:41 kaspar-pc kernel: [18312.601860] ptrace of pid 5563 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:39:41 kaspar-pc kernel: [18312.601915] ptrace of pid 8585 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:39:41 kaspar-pc kernel: [18312.608335] ptrace of pid 4064 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:39:41 kaspar-pc kernel: [18312.608402] ptrace of pid 4068 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:39:41 kaspar-pc kernel: [18312.608454] ptrace of pid 4076 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:40:44 kaspar-pc kernel: [18376.177046] yama_ptrace_access_check: 4 callbacks suppressed
Feb 23 00:40:44 kaspar-pc kernel: [18376.177051] ptrace of pid 4064 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:40:44 kaspar-pc kernel: [18376.177103] ptrace of pid 4068 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:40:44 kaspar-pc kernel: [18376.177154] ptrace of pid 4076 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
Feb 23 00:40:44 kaspar-pc kernel: [18376.177204] ptrace of pid 4085 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 4058)
```

I have no idea how to make the list appear correctly..  But as I can see from `syslog` there is only lines about wine there and not my problem. So I probably need to look into some other logs but which ones.

Updated log which i ran for half an hour:

```
kaspar@kaspar-pc:~$ tail -F /var/log/syslog
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.563462] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.563502] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.563537] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.563572] ptrace of pid 18082 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.568618] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.568661] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.568697] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26160.568733] ptrace of pid 18082 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26161.074357] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:10:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [26161.074413] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217175] yama_ptrace_access_check: 23 callbacks suppressed
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217181] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217218] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217254] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217292] ptrace of pid 18082 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217500] ptrace of pid 18109 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217536] ptrace of pid 18124 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:03 kaspar-pc kernel: [26391.217571] ptrace of pid 18429 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:04 kaspar-pc kernel: [26392.427695] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:04 kaspar-pc kernel: [26392.427737] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:04 kaspar-pc kernel: [26392.427775] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:14:58 kaspar-pc cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.
tail: `/var/log/syslog' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
tail: cannot watch `/var/log/syslog': Permission denied
tail: cannot watch `/var/log/syslog': Permission denied
tail: `/var/log/syslog' has appeared;  following end of new file
Feb 23 11:16:13 kaspar-pc anacron[12106]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Feb 23 11:16:13 kaspar-pc anacron[12106]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Feb 23 11:17:02 kaspar-pc CRON[18745]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994551] yama_ptrace_access_check: 5 callbacks suppressed
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994556] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994594] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994631] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994667] ptrace of pid 18082 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994702] ptrace of pid 18109 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994738] ptrace of pid 18124 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.994773] ptrace of pid 18429 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.999638] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.999678] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:12 kaspar-pc kernel: [28437.999714] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [28463.842282] yama_ptrace_access_check: 4 callbacks suppressed
Feb 23 11:48:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [28463.842288] ptrace of pid 18061 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [28463.842339] ptrace of pid 18065 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [28463.842390] ptrace of pid 18074 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
Feb 23 11:48:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [28463.842441] ptrace of pid 18082 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 18055)
```

The time stamps when stuttering occurred we're 11.21 11.31 11.36 11.41 and 11.46
According to that log, nothing happened at those times.

Logs from kern.log

```
    kaspar@kaspar-pc:~$ tail -F /var/log/kern.log
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.438757] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.438797] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.438833] ptrace of pid 22775 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.438868] ptrace of pid 22784 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.440681] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.440716] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.440751] ptrace of pid 22775 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:38 kaspar-pc kernel: [33595.440785] ptrace of pid 22784 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:39 kaspar-pc kernel: [33596.007100] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:13:39 kaspar-pc kernel: [33596.007139] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269211] yama_ptrace_access_check: 23 callbacks suppressed
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269216] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269257] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269296] ptrace of pid 22775 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269335] ptrace of pid 22784 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269374] ptrace of pid 22816 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269413] ptrace of pid 22831 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:36 kaspar-pc kernel: [33893.269452] ptrace of pid 23091 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:37 kaspar-pc kernel: [33894.217138] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:37 kaspar-pc kernel: [33894.217192] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:18:37 kaspar-pc kernel: [33894.217243] ptrace of pid 22775 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.769962] yama_ptrace_access_check: 5 callbacks suppressed
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.769968] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.770047] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.770107] ptrace of pid 22775 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.770159] ptrace of pid 22784 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.770209] ptrace of pid 22816 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.770259] ptrace of pid 22831 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.770310] ptrace of pid 23091 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.778003] ptrace of pid 22763 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.778045] ptrace of pid 22767 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
    Feb 24 18:57:59 kaspar-pc kernel: [36252.778093] ptrace of pid 22775 was attempted by: wineserver (pid 22757)
```

Seeing this log it seems that once again the error does not want to show up.
Edit:
Linking some screenshots with         top monitoring the moment the stutter occurs. Maybe it helps a bit.
[image: Before stutter]
[image: stutter]

As it can be seen, when stutter occurs, Xorg is taking up a lot of processing power from one core. This time it was only 12.6% but the nastier ones take up to 37% which causes a real lock-down for a couple of seconds.
Also I wonder if this is Xorg making the error, should I not look at Xorg logs? But which one should I be monitoring as there are so many of them. Also when I tried to monitor Xorg.3.log it did not show any timestamps for it's errors so it might be hard to read stuff from there I guess.

Comment: Have you `tail -F`'d some of the log files under `/var/log` (most interestingly `syslog`) while the problem occurs? This way you may be able to figure out what's running. My *guess* would be `cron` job is giving the trouble. If it's that regular it sounds like `cron` or one of the other similar programs.

Comment: Updated with logs, I have really now idea how to use the listing system here ...

Comment: you would obviously have to provide output from one of those 7 min cycles, not just the last few lines. Basically, open a terminal, then play your thing and check what's in the output and looks fishy every 7 minutes. If those are a lot of lines, use a pastebin.

Comment: Judging from the last log it seems syslog is not the one to look at for this error? Should I monitor Xorg log maybe or what?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I would try `kern.log`if `syslog` doesn't give anything useful. But keep in mind that the problem could just as well be purely in hardware and we're chasing a "ghost" then ...

Comment: I will be trying to check that log also soon then. I doupt that it is my hardware, I installed this Linux distro 1 month ago and it started to occur only with after that. Before I had a win 7 on this laptop and there was no problem. But for the sake of being 100% sure I will install win 7 on a seperate partition soon to see if it is so. EDIT: Also I was trying to look for help for this problem on ubuntuforums.org and there seems to be a wooping number of people who are having the exact same problem as I do. I  do think that it might be some software bug what is causing this.

Comment: I have made a fresh installation of windows 8 on the same machine now and the stuttering is not occurring on it. It is definently a software problem and more specificly a Xorg problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your AMD Graphics Drivers installed, you can download them [here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

If that doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling xorg using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg
```

then

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg`

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a game error (or bug). Try reinstalling the game, or reinstall Ubuntu. It might help to get more RAM and a 64 bit version of Ubuntu. Also, laptops are always slower that PC#s.

Comment: I think reinstalling Ubuntu completely would be a bit extreme solution. But it occurs when gaming and watcing videos and probably  even when doing browsing, but I cannot feel it that well then.